# Method is not a function in watcher callback vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm coding a project with vueJS. I've a component with following code :

```
import ProjectsStore from './../stores/ProjectsStore.js';

export default {
    store: ProjectsStore,
    data () {
        return {
            loading: false,
            randomProject: null,
        }
    },
    computed: {
        projects () {
            return this.$store.state.projects;
        },
        commits () {
            return this.$store.state.commits;
        }
    },
    methods : {
        setCommit : ()=> {
            // code here
        }
    },
    watch: {
        projects: (value) => {
            this.setCommit()
        }
    },
    mounted () {
        this.$store.dispatch('loadProjectsList')
    }
}
```

I've following error in projects watch callback :

```
this.setCommit is not a function
```

I put a `console.log (this)` in callback and it displays an default object not a VueComponent.

Did I make something wrong ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not 100% on this but try changing your function definition from `setCommit: () => {}` to `setCommit() {}`. Maybe the same for the projects method, too.

Comment: It's exactly that. Thanks you very much ! I'm a newbie in ES6, I didn't know the difference.

Comment: No problem, I'm a newbie too. That's just the way I've always done it. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Instead of trial and error of changing the syntax and to see what works, its better if you understand why a particular piece of code works.

As mentioned in the vue [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Properties-and-Methods):

Don’t use arrow functions on an instance property (e.g. `vm.$watch('a', newVal => this.myMethod())`). As arrow functions are bound to the parent context, **this** will not be the Vue instance as you’d expect and `this.myMethod` will be undefined.

If you are new to es6 arrow functions [here](https://derickbailey.com/2015/09/28/do-es6-arrow-functions-really-solve-this-in-javascript/) is a pretty good explantion of arrow function's **this** binding works.

Once you clearly understand then no more trial and error

Hope my answer was of some help to you

Comment: A callback is an example of when you *should* use an arrow function.

Comment: @BertEvans are you telling me or to miceli who asked the question. Sorry bit confused?

Comment: You. You state in your answer, "Don’t use arrow functions on an instance property or callback". Instance property is correct. Callback is not.

Comment: The documentation you are referring to is defining the callback outside the Vue. In that specific case, it would be broken. I would say that's an atypical case though. In most cases, someone is going to be making an API call (this.$http or axios) or something like that inside a Vue method or lifecycle event and in those cases, using an arrow function to define the callback is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: @BertEvans yup i understand that, thank you for pointing it out

Comment: You saved my life! Switching from arrow to anonymous function in the watch worked for me. Thanks.